# Glassfish does not detect the JAX-WS endpoint

Tags: glassfish, http-status-code-404, jax-ws

Hello am facing a problem in the glassfish server
I have deployed my application with intellij and it has shown me the first page of the Hello World successfully and when I add to the url the name of the service a 404page has been shown

This is the code of the webservice

```
 package test;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(serviceName = "HelloService")
public class Hello {
    public Hello() {
    }

    @WebMethod()
    public int calcul (int a , int b){
        return a+b;
    }

}
```

the web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

the index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Test the application the problem is that the glassfish can't access to the webservers</h1>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is when I run the application for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y3XZ.png)

[This is when I add the webservice name to the url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V06mP.png)

[This is the Glassfish5 GUI showing it doesn't detect the components of the new webservices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSEKy.png)

Answer (score 0):

After i tried again and again
I found in other WAR files that the web.xml don't exist
so i deleted the web.xml file and

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).